# Java Stream API filter

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have code:

```
static void doSmth() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        list.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    list.stream().filter("1329"::contains).map(s -> s + "a").forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Why i got:

```
 1a
 2a
 3a
 9a
 13a
 29a
```

I expected a empty output, because list doesn't contains "1329".

Comment: "1329" does contain "1", "2", "3", "9", "13", and "29".

Comment: `"1329"::contains` is the issue. It expands to `s -> "1329".contains(s)` which is not what you want. Instead the behaviour you are looking for is `"1329"::equals`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

because

```
.filter("1329"::contains)
```

mean

```
.filter(s -> "1329".contains(s))
```

not

```
.filter(s -> s.contains("1329"))
```

As I guess you think it means.

So your list hold :

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ... 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
    ^  ^  ^                 ^               ^                           ^
```

Which `"1329"` contains `1,2, 3, 9, 13 and 29`

Answer (score 2):

That's because when you are iterating from 0 to 29, the `.contains` just checks if each individual element in the list is present or not in the string `1329`.

Since 1,2,3... are present they return true, hence they get mapped and appended with "a". If you want to check whether the *entire* string `1329` is present then use the `.equals()`

```
filter("1329"::equals)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the above output because you are using "1329" Java String to check whether it contains any of the Strings from the list. Since String "1329" contains ["1", "2", "3", "9", "13", "29"], so it filters them out and then you are appending "a" to each filtered string.

In order to check whether the list contains "1329", you can directly use contains() method on java.utit.List. It should fetch the empty set since the list doesn't contain "1329" String.

In order to fetch the Strings from the list which are equal to "1329", you can use the filter method along with String equals method.

```
list
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> "1329".equals(s))
    .map(s -> s + "a")
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Now, in your case the above code will give nothing in output since the list doesn't contain "1329" String.